# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"fault") after migrating from AXIS to CXF

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl, cxf

### The Problem

I am trying to migrate my web service *client* from **Apache AXIS-1** to **Apache CXF**.  The web service itself runs om AXIS-1 and is out of my control.
I generated all the CXF artifacts and the client has been working well until any fault is thrown by the service. The faulty XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Remote error processing component card request</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <fault>
          <faultcode>:-303</faultcode>
          <faultstring>Remote error processing component card request</faultstring>
          <faultactor>remote_service</faultactor>
          <detail>
            <common-detail>
              <code>-303</code>
              <message>Remote error processing component card request</message>
            </common-detail>
          </detail>
        </fault>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This makes the CXF generated client fall with exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"fault"). 
Expected elements are <{http://some.namespace.org}AnsBonusAutopayStatus>,<{http://some.namespace.org}AnsBonusAutopaySubscribe>,
...
<{http://some.namespace.org}fault>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:603)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:239)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1009)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:446)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:427)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:123)
...
```

AFAIU from this stacktrace, unmarshaller expects the **fault** element to have certain namespace declaration but it comes without one.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with that client and how to avoid the error?

### Tested Solutions

There are a lot of similar questions but not all the solutions are applicable for me because I can't change anything on the server side (at least for backward compatibility reasons) and changing the WSDL is also not appreciated. Thus changes are restricted in client side only (including its (re)generation).
I've tried several possible solutions based on similar questions:

- adding **package-info.class** with default namespace declaration - nothing changes;
- force setting empty namespace for generated **Fault** and/or **Fault_Exception** classes - **NullPointerException** in CXF routines during constructing the exception object (see EDIT section below);
- using **SAX XmlFilter** - couldn't find a way to embed it into CXF generated routines.

### Additional Info

CXF generated classes for exception and its faultInfo (without any of my changes) look like:
**Fault** class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "faultcode",
    "faultstring",
    "faultactor",
    "detail"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "fault")
public class Fault {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String faultcode;
...
```

**Fault_Exception** class:

```
@WebFault(name = "fault", targetNamespace = "http://some.namespace.org")
public class Fault_Exception extends Exception {

    private Fault fault;

    public Fault_Exception() {
        super();
    }
...
```

Some WSDL excerpts.
**WSDL Fault** message declaration:

```
  <wsdl:message name="Fault">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" element="fault"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

**XSD fault** element:

```
<xs:element name="fault">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="faultcode">...</xs:element>
    <xs:element name="faultstring">...</xs:element>
    <xs:element name="faultactor">...</xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="detail">...</xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**WSDL operation description** example:

```
<wsdl:operation name="BonusConversionState">
  <wsdl:input name="BonusConversionStateRequest" message="tns:BonusConversionStateRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output name="BonusConversionStateResponse" message="tns:BonusConversionStateResponse"/>
  <wsdl:fault name="Fault" message="tns:Fault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

**WSDL root element:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://some.namespace.org" 
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                  xmlns:tns="http://some.namespace.org" 
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
```

More additional info can be provided.
Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

During "investigation" I've found out that *NullPointerException* (that I mentioned in "Tested Solutions") is not a consequence of my faulty actions. It's a bug of CXF:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2555;
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3763.

Both tickets are closed with resolution "Fixed", but in comments users report they still catch this bug. It seems that developers did not cover all the cases where custom exceptions are handled by CXF and for some reasons it sometimes leads to

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter processFaultDetail
>   INFO: Exception occurred while creating exception: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Has anybody ever faced this problem too?

Comment: I've found a workaround for the issue but it can't recommended as a good solution.

Comment: The idea of the workaround briefly.
After setting explicit empty namespace on generated `Fault` class, the incoming interceptor chain should be enriched with `XSLTInInterceptor`. The interceptor (through XSLT) should export all the sensible data (fault code and message) from inner element to the topmost `soapenv:Fault` level. This should help to avoid the CXF bug issues. After that the client code should be modified to obtain error info from `SOAPFaultException` (not generated exception class).
Be careful, the solution may worsen performance (increase client methods CPU execution time).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a case of the service not complying with its own contract where the fault is concerned.  While you may not have control of the service, this is worth a discussion with the service provider.

The fault element your client is complaining about is the immediate child of the first 'detail' element.

Based on the exception message, the first child element of 'detail' is expected to be (assuming target namespace 'http://some.namespace.org') either AnsBonusAutopayStatus or AnsBonusAutopaySubscribe and not the {}fault element.

If you are able to provide a bit more of the wsdl around the fault declaration in the operation and the wsdl types additional static analysis can be provided.

Comment: Thank you, dcbyers! I've added some more info from WSDL. Hope this will help.
You're right, the problem is in the first child element of `detail` element which is the root element for custom exception object. CXF cannot find an appropriate class for deserialization of custom exception due to namespace declaration differences. The problem can be worked around by explicit empty namespace declaration on generated Fault class but this approach reveals a bug in CXF itself (see EDIT section of the question). Searching for other ways...